# Deriving GQLType or Generic for UTCTime

Tags: haskell, graphql

I am trying to work with Morpheus-Graphql (https://morpheusgraphql.com/) to builda graphql webservice. I have the following record type I want to serialize:

```hs
import Data.Time (UTCTime)

data Comment = Comment
  { commentId = Int
  , comment = Text
  , when = UTCTime
  } deriving (Generic, GQLType)
```

However `UTCTime` cannot be derived using `Generic`. I have looked into creating an instance of `Generic` for `UTCTime` and have not found the right approach. Alternatively I have tried to create an instance of `GQLType` using

```
instance GQLType UTCTime where
  type KIND UTCTime = SCALAR
```

which then requires an implementation of `EncodeScalar` which is not visibile to me.

My goal here is to just make the `when` field serialize to and from an ISO string.

Any help how to approach this correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the documentation you linked, you should implement instances of EncodeScalar and DecodeScalar for your type. Do you get an error if you try to do this?

Comment: I actually managed to do it now. I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually was able to solve this myself using the following implementation:

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Morpheus.Types
import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601  

instance EncodeScalar UTCTime where                                                                     
  encodeScalar = String . T.pack . iso8601Show                                                          
                                                                                                        
instance DecodeScalar UTCTime where                                                                     
  decodeScalar (String s) = iso8601ParseM $ T.unpack s
  decodeScalar _ = Left "Cannot decode from type"
```

Comment: decodeScalar should have a second pattern which fails to parse any non-string value, otherwise your program will crash unceremoniously when it finds ill formed data.